# Expressing the differential equation characterization of $\sin(x)$ in first-order logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory, predicate-logic

The function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $x\mapsto sin(x)$ is the unique function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that

1. $f(0)=0$.
2. $f'(0)=1$.
3. $f''+f=0$.

**How do we express these properties characterizing $\sin(x)$ as sentences using first-order predicates in an appropriate first-order language $\mathcal{L}$? Do we need to express additional properties, such as that $\sin(x)$ is everywhere differentiable?**

This what I have so far: Consider $\mathbb{R}$ as the $\mathcal{L}$-structure $M:=(\mathbb{R},+,-,\times,0,1,<,=)$, i.e. the real ordered field. Then, the language $\mathcal{L}$ has ternary predicates $\dot{+}, \dot{-}, \dot{\times}$, a binary predicate $\dot{<}$, constants $\dot{0},\dot{1}$, and equality $\dot{=}$.

Viewing the function $\sin(x)$ as binary relation $r$ on the domain of $M$- i.e., $(a,b)\in r$ simply means $b=\sin(a)$; we introduce a new binary predicate $R$ in $\mathcal{L}$. I gather that we must now write that no matter how $R$ is interpreted as a relation $R^{M}$ in $M$, if 1-3 appropriately expressed are satisfied, then $r=R^{M}$.

Indeed, 1 should be the $\mathcal{L}$-sentence $R\dot{0}\dot{0}$ (or $\dot{0}R\dot{0}$ if you prefer to write it like that) since, when intepreted, it will mean $(0,0)\in R^{M}$.

However, I have a problem expressing the first and second derivatives. I guess we do need to use the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition and perhaps add new symbols to the language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if the graph of the function $f$ is defined by $\varphi_f(x,y)$, let's write down the definition of $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L$. Note that this is a formula $\psi_f(a,L)$ with two free variables $a$ and $L$.

\begin{align*}
\forall \varepsilon\, (\varepsilon > 0\to \exists \delta\, (\delta > 0\land \forall x\,(((a-\delta < x) \land (x \neq a)\land (x < a+\delta)) \to\\ \exists y\, (\varphi_f(x,y)\land (L-\varepsilon < y) \land (y < L+\varepsilon))))
\end{align*}

Now to define the derivative, note that $f'(a) = L$ exactly when $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} = L$. So we can define $f'$ by the formula $\psi_g(a,L)$ above, where $g$ is the function $g(x,a) = \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ (which depends on the parameter $a$). If the graph of $f$ is defined by $\varphi_f(x,y)$, then the graph of $g$ is defined by $\varphi_g(x,y,a)$: $$x\neq a\land \exists z\, \exists w\,(\varphi_f(x,z)\land \varphi_f(a,w)\land (y\times (x-a) = z - w)).$$
We can drop the $x\neq a$ clause at the beginning if we only use the value $y$ in situations where we know $x \neq a$.

Putting these observations together, we can express your second condition $f'(0) = 1$ (writing $R(x,y)$ for the graph of $f$, as in your question) by substituting $\varphi_g$ for $\varphi_f$ in the definition of $\psi_f$ and substituting $0$ and $1$ for $a$ and $L$.

\begin{align*}
\forall \varepsilon\, (\varepsilon > 0\to \exists \delta\, (\delta > 0\land \forall x\,(((-\delta < x) \land (x \neq 0)\land (x < \delta))\\ \to \exists y\, ((\exists z\, \exists w\,(R(x,z)\land R(a,w))\land (y\times x = z - w))\\\land (1-\varepsilon < y) \land (y < 1+\varepsilon))))
\end{align*}

I'll leave it to you to write down a formula $\varphi_{f''}(x,y)$ for the graph of $f''$ (which involves nesting the above construction). But once you do, you can express $f''+f = 0$ by: $$\forall x\, \exists y\, \exists z\, (\varphi_{f''}(x,y)\land R(x,z)\land y+z = 0)$$

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write a detailed, clear answer. Is there a particular reason why you use $\varphi_{f}(x,y)$ instead of just $R(x,y)$ from the start to express the graph of $f$? What motivates my question is not notation, but perhaps a method or way of thinking about the problem that is general, and I should learn.

Comment: Yes, it's because I wanted to apply the definition of $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L$ not just to the function $f$ defined by $R$, but also to other functions defined in terms of $f$ (in this case $g$). So I wanted to write it in general: whenever $f$ is a function defined by $\varphi_f(x,y)$, we can define the derivative... This is crucial when you want to take second derivatives etc.